# ExtJs Calendar Documentation or some example code?

Tags: documentation, extjs, calendar

I have included the necessary files for the ExtJs calendar. 
However I'm having difficulty finding documentation or an example on how to use the calendar.
I have looked into the example on the Ext website itself and I still can't seem to grasp it.
If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a list of demo's on the original project's site (from which ExtJS took the core calendar component):

http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/

Maybe that will help get you going.

Comment: Thanks! I have start to modify basic example to try rendering calendar date from database with ajax tecnology, but it is not easy to modify like i have thought.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at these links:

1. [Ext JS Calendar plugin](http://ext.ensible.com/)
2. [Calendar support forum](http://ext.ensible.com/forum/)
3. [Installing Extensible Calendar Pro with ExtJS](http://mutinyworks.com/blog/2013/08/15/installing-extensible-calendar-with-extjs-tutorial-extjs-4-2-x/)
4. [Ext JS Calendar agenda view with interesting demo (examples folder)](https://github.com/gsidler/Extensible)
5. [More examples with custom features](http://www.teamup.com/products-1/live-demo.html)
6. http://www.teamup.com/products-1/live-demo.html